# Maven shade plugin to include all dependency jars

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am facing an issue while packaging jar using maven in eclipse. I believe its taking only the dependency classes that are required during compile time.. There are classes that are required at the run time and its not including it. Is there a way to force Maven to include all dependency jars/classes while building the final jar.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                           <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                  <!--      <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude> 
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude> -->
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer
                                 implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass></mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>


                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) seems to indicate that it includes all the dependencies scoped `compile` and `runtime`. Have you tried to confirm if this is not the case with a minimal sample project?

Comment: I just found all the dependencies were packaged. The issue was I had a spring bean xml config file that was not able to be found even though the path exists. Then I figured out there is a way to combine java + spring during executing mvn package. I had to add the below to pom.xml to make it work.                   <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
              <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
            </transformer>
                            </transformers>

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. I am using Apache maven shade plugin

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.myname.sample_client.Application</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

- Note Mine is a spring boot application so I have transformers for it.